# Floating Views using Window Manager android

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

i am able to float a drawable using float manager but how do i make a layout or a view float? below is my code-                                                                    (i am new to android and coding please be patient)

```
public class example extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageView(this);

        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

        try {
            chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        // Get current time in nano seconds.

                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, paramsF);
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. Working like a charm plus 1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

To float a view use ListPopupWindow and inflate data in list.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html

open listview on chatHead clickListener.

I hope it will help.